# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, execute

```
$sql = "UPDATE Student ".
           "SET score = $total_score ".
           "WHERE student_id = $student_id";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $query = "SELECT faculty_id ".
             "From Student s ".
             "WHERE student_id =$student_id";
    $state =$mysqli->prepare($query);
    $state->execute();
    $state->bind_result($faculty_id);
    if ($state->fetch())
    {if (strpos($faculty_id, '1') > 0) {
            include ('./Registration_Step_3_Student.php');
        } else 
        {
            include ('./Registration_Step_3_Mentor.php');
        }   
    }
```

So whenever i try to run my second query called $state, i get this error that states it cannot be execute. I am relatively new to SQL and PHP so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Probably the `s` in `From Student s` - You might have pressed `CTRL-S` to save, but it failed, entering an `s`. It's happened to me before.

Comment: still seems to yield the same output on the website

Comment: This `"From Student s ".` shouldn't that be `"From Student ".` or `Students`? There's a space between `Student` and the `s` which seems thh most likely error.

Comment: no i dont think thats the problem, for example im getting the same error with the allowing code as well:

   $query = "UPDATE Student ".
           "SET student_password = '" . $student_password . "', phone_number = '" . $phone_number . "', location = '" . $location . "', skype_address ='" . $skype_address . "' ".
                 "WHERE student_id ='" . $student_id ."''" ;
   $state =$mysqli->prepare($query);
   $state->execute();
   include ('./Registration_Step_2.php');

Comment: So what's the `s` for?

Comment: This from your comment above `"WHERE student_id ='" . $student_id ."''"; ` seems like you have an extra quote `'` and should be `"WHERE student_id ='" . $student_id ."'"; `

Comment: well i guess technically it's a typo where i tried to call my Student table s but i didnt end up calling the columns using s.user_name or anything like that. I seem to be able to get the first code working, but the second code is giving me tons of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `mysqli` you should learn how to bind properly, please read up on [`bind_Param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[`mysqli_stmt::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) returns an false when failing, you should never execute the statement when it does:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Student SET score = ? WHERE student_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if($stmt){
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $total_score, $student_id);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $query = "SELECT faculty_id From `Student s` WHERE student_id = ?";
        $state =$mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $student_id);
        if($state->execute()){
            var_dump($state->fetch());
        }else{
            echo 'SELECT failed';
             printf("Error: %s.\n", $state->error);
        }       
    }else{
       echo 'failed to execute UPDATE';
    }
}else{
      echo 'failed to prepare() UPDATE \n';
       printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: oh and please double check your syntax, `SELECT faculty_id From Student s WHERE student_id = ?` does not look right